# Why cant I append a label in my Array?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting the value of dateChanged from `datePicker` in a variable and then I append that variable in my String Array. Then I print that StringArray into my TableView cell but I cant figure out why it is not working. Here is the code where I declare the time as a global Variable :

```
    var time: [String] = []

    func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

    let mydate="adding reminder on \(dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date))"

    time.append(mydate)
  }
```

Then I try to print the value in my TableViewCell by code :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellID") as! CustomCell
cell.dateLabel?.text=time[indexPath.row]
return (cell)
```

And this is the code to my CustomCell class :

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
} 
  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

 }
}
```

[image: Here is the error]

Comment: You didn't put the value in the `dateLabel.text`

Comment: can you print out `time[indexPath.row]` in the `cellForRowAt` ? Just double check the value's existence, if the value exists, it's the layout problem.

Comment: have you called `tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: @Tj3n yes in my `commit editingStyle`

Comment: @WeiJay I cant get to my TableView...The button that shows my TableView is when tapped throws a SIGABRT.

Comment: It's not proper to use `dataLabel.text` like that. You can create a new variable `let myDate = "adding ...."` then `time.append(myDate)`. And when layout the tableview, it just take the value out of `time` and put in your `dateLabel.text` of your `CustomCell`

Comment: @WeiJay I've edited my code and used the append(mydate) but how do I use it in my `cellForRowAt` ?....I didnt understand the way you told.

Comment: @S.Verma , after appending you must reload the tableview :). Also on your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `time.count`

Comment: are you refresh the tableview or not after append the data

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S reload my tableView in my `cellForRowAt` ? but how do I print the value in the label ? because `cell.dateLabel?.text=time[indexPath.row]` throws `SIGABRT`

Comment: reload tableview after this line `time.append(mydate)`

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S I already have return(list.count) in my `numberofRowsInSection` so I can not return two values.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR but my `TableView` is not in the same class as `time.append(mydate)` so I can not use it.

Comment: @S.Verma , let check the indices of `list` and `time` have same value else you can get `Array index out of Range` exception

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S yes they have same values..list is one String Array and time is another. and they have same return value.

Comment: If tableview isnt in same class then how can u access `time` array in `cellForRowAt indexPath` method?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR because time array is a Global Variable.

Comment: @S.Verma , can you able to update your question with screen shot of desired error on cosole?

Comment: In which class you have the method `datePickerValueChanged` and how you are navigating `to ReminderViewController`?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR I have my `datePickerValueChanged` in the same class where I have the `datePicker`

Comment: What is the class name and is it a separate View controller?

Comment: The class name is `SecondPageViewController` and yes it is separate. I have my `tableView` in `ReminderViewController`

Comment: @S.Verma, It mean `list.index.count` is not equal to `time.index.count`. You will check it on `number of RowsInSection`.

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S so how do I make them equal because I can not return 2 values in the same function.

Comment: In `numberOfRowsInSection` method compare `list.count` and `time.count` and return which is smaller.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR I'm using `if(list.count<time.count){
            return list.count
        }
        else{
            return time.count
        }` but I see a blank `TableView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `numberOfRowsInSection` method return `list.count`

and in `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```
cell.dateLabel?.text = time.indices.contains(indexPath.row) ? time[indexPath.row] : "Not Available"
```

Comment: I think `time.count` is 0.

Comment: but I am getting the same result of time for every `tableView` the time that I want to display in my cell is static (like the one which I set on the first time)

Comment: Can you upload the project in dropbox and share?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWwjHdOZO2LQmoyQnZLV1M1b28/view?usp=sharing Thank you.

Comment: I have no problem. Without reminders - http://prnt.sc/ekjo5l and with one reminder - http://prnt.sc/ekjo2s

Comment: @S.Verma https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2muDTh8K38QeDdhVmwwenlYZ1U/view Try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138177/discussion-between-s-verma-and-rajeshkumar-r).

Answer (score 0):

Please modify these line in you code and test it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //other lines you want
    return time.count //Not get index out of range error
}
```

you return list.count but not time.count. it's may be possible if list array is less than time arr then possible to index out of range.